# letting-in two-ply 2x12 girder to 6x6 beam

Tags: carpentry

I am doing a project where I'm supporting a girder made of two 2x12s with a 6x6 post.  (But this question really applies to 2-by-anything).   For added strength, I want to "let in" the girder to the 6x6, that is, cut a notch out of the top of the 6x6 for the girder to sit in; this is superior, because the girder is supported directly by the 6x6, not just by the fasteners.

[image]

I will also add a diagonal brace, probably 2x6.

Several questions:

1. What is the best way to notch the 6x6 ?   In the past, with one 2-by, I've made a series of kerfs with my circular saw, and then cleaned it out with chisel/hammer/etc.   But my circular saw can only cut to 2-1/4".   How well would it work to make cuts down both sides of the 6x6, which would leave about 1" of material in the 6x6 (actual thickness 5-1/2"), and finish up with a sawzall, which would be guided pretty accurately by the previous two 2-1/4" deep cuts ?
2. Should I consider making the notch less than 3" deep, perhaps the 2-1/4" my circular saw could manage with the kerf & cleanout method ?  I intend to thoroughly bolt the two 2x12s together, and the notch would still support half of the second one, so no worries on strength there.   In fact, I fear that by making the notch 3" deep, I would leave only 2-1/2" of the 6x6 where the girder is bolted, which would weaken the connection a good bit.
3. If I decide to make the notch only 2-1/4" deep, how do I make my diagonal brace lay nicely ?  The girder would stick out 3/4" from the side of the post, so there will be a 3/4" gap between the brace and the side of the post.   Maybe just put a "washer" of 3/4" thick wood between the brace and the 6x6 ?

**ADDIITONAL CONTEXT:**

This will be outdoors, so the wood will be treated, probably using MCA (micronized copper azole), which is supposedly gentler on metal fasteners and non-toxic.

This is for a ground-mount solar array.   The girders will support aluminum rails to which the solar panels are clamped.   I believe this means that the strongest forces will be wind uplift, not downwards.  I had to get a PE to stamp some drawings for the permit (below).   I am deviating a bit (with AHJ's blessing), using metal rails instead of the 2x8 purlins shown in the drawings.   But I will do the footings/piers, posts, and girders as shown in the drawings, except possibly making the notches only 2-1/4" deep as mentioned above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW, this is completely separate from my recent question about adding knee braces to strengthen an undersized beam.   These knee braces are only to keep the joint at a right angle.

Comment: Don’t you think it would be important to identify the location or identify the wind loading design criteria, if you think wind upload is critical? Also, if you think you might change the “railings”, don’t you think it would be important to identify what in the heck is a “railing” on the drawings? (I don’t see the word “railing” on the drawings.)

Comment: What is the spacing of the 6x6 posts and 24” dia. concrete supports? What is the size of the thru bolts?

Comment: As I said, there was a design done by a PE, who looked at the various loading; they are 115mph wind with "wind exposure B" and 20psf snow load.   I don't see the need to re-think that.  The spacing of the piers and 6x6s is 7.5ft in theNS direction and 12.5ft in the EW direction (I believe that's in the drawings, though not quite the same).

Comment: Two 1/2" HDG bolts - connecting the 6x6 to ABU66Z post bases (which is what Simpson specs for that part) and two 1/2" bolts for the connection in question.

Comment: No "railings", but rails. Several companies have pre-engineering railing systems for mounting solar panels, on roofs as well as free-standing "ground mount". I am using this system: ironridge.com/ground-based except I'm replacing the locally-sourced horizontal and vertical pipes with the treated wood we're discussing here.  Thus the IronRidge rails (specifically the XR1000 model) replace the 2x8 purlins in the drawings.

Comment: I sorry to hear that you don’t “need to rethink that.” I thought you were considering the possibility of dapping the 2x12’s into the 6x6’s a full 3” or just 2 1/4”. In order to make that determination we need to calculate load (uplift) and resistance (dead load).  I won’t bother you with the calculations, (because you’ve already accepted an answer that says “it looks about right to me” and “I’ve done it before”) , but the dead load is about 2400 lbs. per frame at 12.5’ on center AND the uplift is about 2300 lbs. per frame section. So, IMO the notching to the full 3” depth is acceptable.

Comment: Oops...I see they are independent structures with overhangs rather than continuous. Change my uplift calculations to about 4000# per frame section and the dead load is about 4800#.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input (not sure what you mean by "frame section" though).   But there's nowhere close to 4800# of dead load, and there's over 5000# of live load from the 20pdf of snow.  Anyhow, the main thing I wanted to know was how best to cut the notch, and that's been answered.  The 3" versus 2-1/4" notch depth is a tangent, in discussion only because I'm not really sure my PE meant to say it needs to be 3", rather just that it needs to be let-in.

Comment: You should consider the possibility of placing the 2x12's one on each side of the post and only cut in 3/4" on each side. This leaves a nice strong 4" center portion of the post to bolt through. When you use this technique you can then set one 2x12 slightly higher on one side of the post so that the 2x8 purlins above can bear on both 2x12's instead of just one. This is very similar to the way we used to build pole barns although the notching at the tops of the poles varied some because round poles were used and they were not all exactly the same diameter at the top.

Comment: An interesting idea, but I don't want to test the AHJ that far (from the permit drawings), and anyhow, as I said, I'm replacing the 2x8 purlins in the drawings with the IronRidge rails and they only attach at one point (using a bracket called an L-foot, check out the link about 5 comments up).   So I'm actually better off sandwiching the 2x12s (a number of thru bolts).   Though I could stagger which 2x12 the L-feet attach to, in your plan.

Comment: @RustyShackleford You’re telling me about snow load and saying “anyway there’s snow load”. You know we don’t count on snow load during the wind calculations. You better hope I’m right that there’s about 4800# of dead load or your frame is going to fly away. (I calculated about 1100# in each concrete base.)

Comment: Yeah right, the concrete is dead load too.

Comment: The ABU66Z is rated for 2190# of uplift, using two 1/2" bolts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that before many times on large beams and it works fine. In fact, forgo the reciprocating saw and still use your chisel. It'll easier than the other method because you'll be working with the grain instead of against it. Or you could use the reciprocating saw to finished the depth on   your cross cuts for your usual method.

The brace is called a knee brace and it's often of evenly dimensioned lumber, usually 4x4, and is usually attached on the face of the beam and post rather than the side. Lag screws are used for attachment, through the knee brace at 45 degree angle which is at the normal 90 degree angle into the post and beam. Usually a counter bore is used to both hide the screw head from view from the side and to provide a flat bearing surface

Comment: You're talking about making the 2-1/4" cuts down the sides of the beam and then finishing with a chisel ?   So I'm chiseling out all 11-1/4" of the 1" wide that remains after those side cuts ?

Comment: Should I make the notch the full 3" deep, or less so that there's more of the 6x6 remaining to bolt onto ?

Comment: Yes, chiseling out 11-1/4". With the grain, one or two hits and it's done, it's MUCH faster, you'll see. Cross cut as usual at the bottom of the notch, and there will be a little more chiseling there because you'll stop your saw at the 11'-1/4" and a piece will be uncut due to the shape of the saw. That will pop off too. The big piece to be removed will pop off easily by putting the chisel into the saw kerf to use like a wedge. I would go the full 3", most of the force is downward and the remaining post piece keeps the beam in place, except for the horizontal forces from the knee brace

Comment: Seems like when I google it, a lot of sites show the notch the full 3" deep and only 2.5" of post remaining.    That's also what the PE drawings (that the AHJ required) show.   Though the AHJs here are pretty reasonable and wouldn't balk at the 2-1/4" depth.

Comment: FYI&FWIW I'm a PE. And in general I have and normally would have no issue with the notch and the remaining amount of post. I don't know the details of your situation but unless it's unusual this is just fine

Comment: See my addendum to the OP, @Ack.

Comment: I'm seriously leaning towards the 2-1/4" notch.   Just don't like how it makes the diagonal brace "unclean".   I could use your method of attaching the brace to the inner faces of the lumber, but that's a little more complicated (limited carpentry skills here) and diverges a bit from what my PE's drawings show.

Comment: It IS a slightly unusual situation, in that because it's for solar panels the wind uplift forces are potentially a lot more than the downward weight.

Comment: well then we need to change the focus from designing for the best gravity connection and instead on the best uplift connection. In that case, even though you don't like it, a metal post cap is your best bet. I see that you just updated your question to include the uplift forces. This changes things. Look at Simpson EPCZ post caps

Comment: Not too worried, since PE signed off on drawings with the 3" notch and nothing else (besides the knee brace).   But, what is this metal post cap of which you speak ?   just a 5.5"-square piece of metal lagged to the top of the connection ?   Seems like a great idea (and cheap and simple).

Comment: I don't understand why then we're discussing this if you already have this answered with a stamped design

Comment: Sorry @Ack , I was trying to keep my question simple, but I have added the drawings to OP.   Main point of discussion (my question #1) is how to implement the post/girder connection spec'd by PE.   Questions #2 and #3 are slight modifications that I believe would improve the strength, as suggested by web-searching for answer to #1.   AHJs here are very reasonable, and would not balk at this slight change.  (Actually, not even sure this is a mod, as he didn't explicitly discuss this connection, the 3" notch is just implicit in the drawing).

Comment: I see no obvious deficiencies, it looks very much like what i would come up with. If you want to increase the uplift resistance at the connection you could add a strap flush between the beam and post, such as a Simpson LSTA x 9" https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-LSTA-1-1-4-in-x-9-in-20-Gauge-Galvanized-Strap-Tie-LSTA9/202255804?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-100375025-_-202255804-_-N

Comment: Ok, thanks, but you don't like the notion of reducing notch to 2-1/4" ?

Comment: That is moving the bar from bearing strength to uplift strength so no, because your engineer already ran the numbers and I'd be second guessing that. I trust that they know what that their doing and you should too, in my opinion. That is a good quality drawing, that indicates a good engineer, if that helps.

Comment: Ok, and thanks for the info on how best to cut the notch.  Will mark answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use what's called a "Cleat" bolted to the post to allow the beam to rest on it. That way you don't end up making your post thinner at the top. Because you are using two 2x's, you would make the cleat out of 4x4 (or 4x6 of you want it to match the width of the post).
[image]

It's a very strong joint based on the weight on the beam being supported as shear strength on the bolts holding the cleat, then the bolts on the beam itself only need to hold the beam against the post.

Added a second version showing forces.
[image]

Comment: I've seen this before, and I don't understand how it's stronger than simply bolting the beam to the post.  The two bolts on the cleat don't have any stronger shear strength than the two bolts on the beam itself, so what have you gained ?   There's the shear strength of 4 bolts instead of 2, but I could just use 4 bolts on the beam itself and forget the cleat.

Comment: Because your beam will want to pull outward under stress, not just push down. So the cleat takes the downward force, the bolts on the beam then only need to handle the outward force.If you put 4 bolts in the beam alone, it helps, but at the same time weakens the strength of the beams by adding 2 more holes.

Comment: Wood connections are complicated. For the beam, the bolts are supporting the wood perpendicular to the grain while the cleat is supported parallel to the grain. The strength of parallel grain bearing is much higher than perp for wood, this is the reason for the strength of this connection. A trade off is that this connection is arguable not as attractive.

Comment: I cut the bottom of the cleat at a bias or even a curve, it helps with the aesthetics... Personally though, I like looking at a joint and feeling safe about how it was made.

Comment: Ok, I understand better, thanks.   But I still believe that the method of notching the top of the beam is stronger.  Then the bolts only need handle the lateral force; the downward weight is supported by the beam itself.   The only caveat is that you weaken the top of the beam some with the notch.   Why I wonder if making the notch only 1.5 board thicknesses wide (instead of 2) is better.

Comment: It might be slightly stronger from a weight bearing standpoint, but if you have a (nominal) 6x6 post it is really  more like 5-1/2" thick, then you want to cut in 2 2x12s that will end up as 3" thick, so you are bolting those laterally onto a sliver of wood that is only 2-1/2" thick and 11-1/2" long. That becomes very weak from any lateral force standpoint.

Comment: I think this might be too focused on the strength of the connection and likely any of these solutions should work. Is it necessary to maximize the capacity of the connection?

Comment: Good point @Ack .   BTW, see my addendum ("ADDITIONAL CONTEXT") to my OP.   I'm also hesitant to diverge this much from the PE drawings required by my AHJ.

Comment: @JRaef that's why I'm thinking of splitting the difference, with a 2-1/4" deep notch bearing 1.5x the thickness of the 2-by board comprising the girder.

Comment: wait you have a design for this? Post the detail! Then let us know what you want different